# Add elements to XDocument after LINQ Query

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5, c#-3.0, linq-to-xml

I have the following XML LINQ query from my XDocument.

```
var totals = (from x in MyDocument.Descendants("TOTALS") select x).FirstOrDefault();
```

Once I have found my totals node I need to add some elements to that node and push that change to the XDocument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So just make the change to the returned node... unless you clone it, it will still be part of the document.

Btw, your query expression isn't adding anything - simpler code would be:

```
var totals = MyDocument.Descendants("TOTALS").FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `AddAfterSelf()` to add new nodes against `totals`. Those changes will automatically get attached to the main XDocument, since totals is referencing an XElement inside the document.

Answer (score -1):

```
totals.Add(new XElement("NewNode", "New node value"));
```

Comment: totals (IEnumerable<XElement>) does not have Add event